# Same alert - Multiple tickers

Tags: pine-script, alerts

How can i make the same alert on many different tickers without having to enter the info hundreds of times? Similiarly, is there a way to change the timeframe or ticker of an already existing alert?

I couldn't find anything to try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html) function to get data from other timeframes and tickers.

Once you have that, create a function for your alert condition. You can use this function for each timeframe/ticker and see if the condition is satisfied. If it is, you can use the `alert()` function to trigger your alert.

By using the `alert()` you would only create one alert (`Any alert() function call` from the drop-down menu) and it will trigger the alert whenever your condition is `true`.

[image]